# How to resolve "Error log file size is increasing in mysql 5.5" issue w/o restarting mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, ubuntu, network, mysqladmin

I have an Ubuntu server with MySQL 5.5 installed. In `/var/lib/mysql` a .err file is kept on updating with these warnings only:

```
[Warning] IP address '234.22.11.221' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
[Warning] IP address '234.22.11.221' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Its size is currently around 2 GB.

I googled this error and in most of the places it has been written that I need to write `skip-host-cache` in `my.cnf` file and then need to give a restart mysql.

Currently this server is carrying lot of running web services, applications and giving a restart may effect all these applications.

As far as I understand, these warnings are not native mysql errors.

Also, can someone tell me whether these warnings effect my database in future if I will not take any action and is it possible that due to other web applications, these errors are generating? What is the other way around for this without restarting mysql?

IS there any probability , that mysql will not come up after restart ???

Answer (score 1):

Put the following parameters in your my.cnf and then restart the service:-

```
skip-name-resolve
log-warnings=1
```

The above activity will solve your  issue.

Try to check this link also:-

https://serverfault.com/questions/341290/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: bit - is restarting mysql only option we have ? what if mysql will not come up ??? im afraid it will impact my ongoing applications

Comment: skip-name-resolve is not a dynamic variable, hence you will have to put this parameter in your cnf file and then restart required. you can change log-warning parameter value dynamically, for this no restart required.

Comment: i have set log_warnings = 0 , but it is not resolving my issue

Comment: you will have to put skip-name-resolve in your cnf to resolve the issue.

Comment: yes , i had already put same..in mysqld section

Comment: Could you provide me the output of below query?show global variables like 'skip_name_resolve';

Comment: Variable_name     | Value |
 skip_name_resolve | OFF   |

Comment: Here skip-name-resolve is off which should be ON to resolve your issue. So to reflect this you will have to restart the MySQL service.

Comment: Please , other than restarting !!

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to Mysql remotely, I got the error.
I had this warning in `/var/log/mysqld.log`:

```
[Warning] IP address 'X.X.X.X' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I just added this line to `/etc/hosts` file:

```
X.X.X.X some_name
```

Problem solved! without using `skip-name-resolve`, it caused some errors in my local app, when connecting to mysql.